# makefile - dependency of dependency

Tags: c++, makefile

From what I've read on the internet you could say that: **A** depends on **B** and **B** depends on **C** -> **A** depends on **C**

So if we have a makefile looking like this:

```
CC=g++

OUTPUT=app.exe

SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))


$(OUTPUT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(OUTPUT) $(OBJECTS)

main.o: main.cpp a.hpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp

a.hpp: b.hpp
```

I would expect `main.o` to be dependent of `b.hpp` and should therefore compile if `b.hpp` is altered after `main.o` was last compiled. But that does not happen.

Have I entirely misunderstood and it doesn't work the way I've described at all? If so, what should the target for main.o look like? Do I have to go through all headers a file includes and also make it dependent off of all of those?

**EDIT**: 
As Sam Miller said, the timestamp of `a.hpp` is not altered even if `b.hpp` has been altered since there is no command which updates `a.hpp`.
Sam Miller suggested the `touch` command. But since I am on windows and was unable to find a simple equivalent I wrote a small program called `WinTouch`. It works very well, thank you all.

**EDIT2** 
Chnossos has showed me I have a lot to learn when it comes to makefiles. I tried the example makefile he put forth and it worked very well and it seems as if it will make life easier for me in the future.

Comment: I'm too lazy now to check, but I guess it's because the command for `a.hpp` (namely, none at all) doesn't update `a.hpp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have I entirely misunderstood and it doesn't work the way I've described at all?

You've got it almost completely, @Sam Miller's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098596/3460805) explain what was missing in your attempt. You need to tell make that `a.hpp` has changed too.

I'd like to address this :

> Do I have to go through all headers a file includes and also make it dependent off of all of those?

GCC or clang can both handle this automatically for you nowadays :

Let's build a simple working example

```make
EXE := app.exe

SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP # built-in variable meant for preprocessor flags, like -I

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
# Linker phase
# LDFLAGS is a built-in variable meant for linker flags such as -L
# LDLIBS is a built-in variable meant for linker flags such as -l
# Their order in the next line IS IMPORTANT to avoid undefined references
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# Makefile include command, litteraly copy and paste its arguments' content into
# the makefile. The dash in the beginning prevent outputting an error if a file
# cannot be found.
-include $(DEP)
```

And that's all you need. Now, for a given `.cpp` file in the folder, you'll have a corresponding `.o` file and a `.d` file that'll track header dependencies for you.
If you want to hide those extra files in a folder, here is how :

```make
EXE := app.exe

SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)
DIR := build
OBJ := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(DIR)/%.o) # toto.cpp => build/toto.o
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d) # build/toto.o => build/toto.d

CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP # built-in variable meant for preprocessor flags, like -I

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
# Linker phase
# LDFLAGS is a built-in variable meant for linker flags such as -L
# LDLIBS is a built-in variable meant for linker flags such as -l
# Their order in the next line IS IMPORTANT to avoid undefined references
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# We need to override the implicit rule for .o files since we want a special
# destination. The right side of the pipe will only be evaluated once, it is
# called "order-only prerequisite".
$(DIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

# Makefile include command, litteraly copy and paste its arguments' content into
# the makefile. The dash in the beginning prevent outputting an error if a file
# cannot be found.
-include $(DEP)
```

If you have any question.

Answer (score 2):

If the target `a.hpp` depends on `b.hpp` you need to indicate that `a.hpp` has changed:

```
a.hpp: b.hpp                                                                                                              
    touch $@
```

this will update the timestamp of a.hpp, triggering the `main.o` target to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

> Have I entirely misunderstood and it doesn't work the way I've
>   described at all?

Targets have dependencies.  When any dependency file changes, make will trigger the actions identified in the make file.

In your file, the target main does not depend on b.hpp, so no action occurs when b.hpp changes.

In your file, the target a.hpp does depend on b.hpp, and what you have is allowed, but you have provided no actions to cause neither a.hpp or main.cpp to be be updated.

Is there a reason you did not simply use?

```
main.o: main.cpp a.hpp b.hpp
$(CC) -c main.cpp
```

> Do I have to go through all headers a file includes and also make  it
>   dependent off of all of those?

What you appear to be missing are dependency files.

The g++ compiler and a sed script can generate and keep them up-to-date for you.

I found the following target and sed many places, but it does take some effort to arrange the files and directories to your liking.  (for instance, I do not like cluttering my src directory with .o or .d files, thus the DEPPATH)

```
$(DEPPATH)/%.d : %.cpp
@echo
@echo R22 :  $<
rm -f  $(addprefix ../i686o/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(@F))))
g++ -M $(CC_FLAGS)  $< > $@.$$$$; sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; rm $@.$$$$
```

Understanding this sed script and the -M option of g++ should get you started.

Well, perhaps it is enough to use the sed as is. I admit I am not a sed guru and I have always used it as I found it.  I did spend time on where I wanted the dependency and object files to reside (relative to the src directory).

Comment: Nowadays this script is not necessary. Compilers like clang or GCC can generate dependency files at the same time they generate linker files (`-MMD` option).

Comment: @Chnossos - Thanks for the update. I had not noticed how old my make files are, I just kept doing what works.